# why setBackBarButtonItem not work in the childViewController viewDIdLoad?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to custom the backBarButtonItem in the navigationItem,
here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                            target:nil
                                                            action:nil];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:back];
}
```

but it didn't work while I used the leftBarButtionItem can work.

I don't know ,can anybody give me an answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelNavButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(dismissController)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:cancelNavButton];
}

- (void)dismissController
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to create the back button yourself if you are pushing your view controllers using the `UINavigationController`'s `pushViewController:animated:` method. This will push the new ViewController on the NavigationControllers stack and give you an automatic back button with the title of the previous ViewController.

The reason your button doesn't work is the `target:` and `action:` parameters are `nil` you could bind them to the `UINavigationController`'s `popViewControllerAnimated:` method to achieve the same action as the default back button.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                    target:[self navigationController]
                                                    action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:)
                                                     ];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:back];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                            target:nil
                                                            action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = back;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't target the "Back" button in the context of a Navigation Controller, but it's the equivalent of overriding the Back button by placing a plain Nav Bar Button on the left side.

Comment: @karthika how to get the < icon in front of the word "Back"?

Comment: [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:newBackButton];